# Assign ID numbers according to groups

Tags: sqlite

Button blue can add blue item, red button adding red button, etc. one button can be clicked more than once, hence there can be more than one blue or red item.

the table is as below

```
item     id      details    size
blue             cheap      small
blue             expensive  big
blue             cheap      small
red              cheap      small
red              ok         average
```

how can i assign the id for each of them so that the table is as below

```
item     id      details    size
blue      1      cheap      small
blue      2      expensive  big
blue      3      cheap      small
red       1      cheap      small
red       2      ok         average
```

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. How is the order of the IDs defined?

Comment: the id will be defined when an item is added. if there is already 2 blue items, then the new blue item will have ID of 3.

Comment: So you don't want to assign all ID number**s**, but you want to find out the next unused ID? If so, please edit the question to say that.

Comment: I wanted to assign everything in the table with ID which is within their respective item category.

Comment: is it possible to do it using sql query? or do i need to check whether ther is registered item with certain ID in the java code of application?

Comment: What is it? "everything" or "when an item is added"?

Comment: when an item is added

Answer (score 0):

Just get the largest ID for the item (use zero if none exists yet), and add one:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1
FROM MyTable
WHERE item = ?;
```